# In what situation we should use Auto-Implemented property in c# instead?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, properties

Just want to know when to practice normal property declaration and auto-implemented properties

private instance variable and property:

```
private string apple;
public string Apple
{
    get{return apple;}
    set{apple=value;}
}
```

The auto-implemented properties:

```
public string Apple {get; set;}
```

Want to know when to use which.

Comment: Basically, if you want to do something additional (either before setting `value` or afterwards, such as update another variable), you can use the normal declaration. Otherwise, you can use the one liner auto-implemented property.

Comment: It's not just logic that requires explicit getters/setters. I often find myself dropping to an explicit backing field if I want a `readonly` backing field. There have been proposals for possible ways to do this with auto properties in both C#6 (primary constructors) and C#7 (Immutable types) but looks like they've both been delayed.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL in what situation it is the best to use auto-implemented property? Can u give some scenario or examples ?

Comment: @SamsonYap I can give scenarios for the other way round, always use auto-implemented properties UNLESS e.g. if you want B to become null when A is set to null, you would put this in A's `set` line: `set{ a=value; if (a == null) B = null; }`. This is the most basic example I could give, but the possibilities are endless.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL , ok thx for your explanation.